# What's the best way to not join on everything exponentially?

Tags: linq, .net-core, linq-to-sql

I have this query in Linq To SQL, .Net Core 3.1.1.

It is pretty self-explanatory that I want to filter on the customer first, and *then* do the joins on Groups and Roles, which could be pretty resource-intensive:

```
await (from customer in _dbContext.Customers
    let groupIds = _dbContext.Groups.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customer.Id).Select(x => x.Id)
    let roleIds = _dbContext.Roles.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customer.Id).Select(x => x.Id)

    where customer.Id == customerId
    select new ResultViewModel
    {
        GroupIds = groupIds.ToList(),
        RoleIds = roleIds.ToList(),
    }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

When I look at the console, I see that it gets translated into this SQL query :

```
  SELECT [t].[Id], [g].[Id], [r].[Id], 
  FROM (
      SELECT TOP(1) [c].[Id]
      FROM [Customer] AS [c]
      WHERE [c].[Id] = @__customerId_0
  ) AS [t]
  LEFT JOIN [Group] AS [g] ON [t].[Id] = [g].[CustomerId]
  LEFT JOIN [Role] AS [r] ON [t].[Id] = [r].[CustomerId]

  ORDER BY [t].[Id], [g].[Id], [r].[Id],
```

**This query makes my database explode.** When I run it in Azure Data studio, I see that the joins complexify the result data exponentially, because I get every possible combination of groups and roles. The filtering on the machine mildly helps reducing the result, and gets applied at the very end. The status bar of Azure Data studio shows that *millions* of rows get involved even though it should be only a few *thousands*.

That's not even the real query. In the real one, instead of joining only on Roles and Groups, I join on 8 other fields.

As a test I've run this and it runs instantly :

```
var customer = _dbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == customerId);
var groupIds = _dbContext.Groups.Where(r => r.CustomerId == customerId).Select(x => x.Id);
var roleIds = _dbContext.Roles.Where(r => r.CustomerId == customerId).Select(x => x.Id);

return new ResultViewModel
{
    GroupIds = groupIds.ToList(),
    RoleIds = roleIds.ToList(),
};
```

**But this is not really an acceptable solution as it's 3 queries (i.e. 3 database connections from my backend) instead of one.**

I'm guessing that it's just a matter of me having incorrectly written the original Ling To Sql query. What did I do wrong? How do avoid those unnecessary joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fast solutions without client-side post processing. So, proposing just fast one.

```
class ConcatSet
{
   public int? GroupId;
   public int? RoleId;
}

var groupIds = _dbContext.Groups.Where(r => r.CustomerId == customerId)
  .Select(x => new ConcatSet { GroupId = x.Id } );

var roleIds  = _dbContext.Roles.Where(r => r.CustomerId == customerId)
  .Select(x => new ConcatSet { RoleId = x.Id } );

var rawData = groupIds.Concat(roleIds).ToList();

// for sure the following lists can be generated more effective by just enumerating rawdData
return new ResultViewModel
{
    GroupIds = rawData.Where(r => r.GroupId != null).Select(r => r.GroupId.Value).ToList(),
    RoleIds  = rawData.Where(r => r.RoleId != null).Select(r => r.RoleId.Value).ToList(),
};
```

You have one roundtrip to database and it should be fastest variant.

Comment: yes, my own investigation showed that at the moment .Net core doesn't know how to populate the extra fields in one query (it does separate database queries under the hood no matter what), the manual solution with separate variables is good enough. Thanks!

Comment: Note: Apparently for advanced, optimized solutions, people use a third-party library called Dapper. There might be improvements in .Net Core 5 as well.

Comment: I'm not using Dapper, but prefer `linq2db` - faster than EF and Dapper